# How to change the image in GridView in android on which user clicks?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am developing a android app in which i have to expand the particular image in the grid view on which user clicks.Is there any way to do it.Any help will be appreciated.I have used two approaches but not achieved the same
[image]
**First: used in getview() method:**

```
    if(array[position]!=null)
                if(array[position].equals("1")){
                 imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80, 1));                   

                }
                imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        final int posit = gridview.getPositionForView((View)v.getParent());
                        array[posit]="1";
                        ((BaseAdapter)gridview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;

                        }
                        return true;
                    }   
                });
```

**Second:**

```
 imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                         v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80, 1));

                         ((BaseAdapter)gridview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                         break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }   
            });
```

But these two methods are not showing the correct result it is expanding the images randomly what should i do. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Shrikant for edit but can you give me some idea to solve it

Comment: what about about using the predefined intent action_view in your onClickListener?

Comment: @Dinesh Venkata but the image should be little bit expanded in the same position to show the show user it is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** : For that problem, you have to keep track of changed views say for example take a Boolean array, when you change view's property, keep true for that position in array. When you scroll view's, whichever array positions are true, for them only you set enlarge property else set default property like below.

```
if(array[position].equals("1"))
{
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80, 1));    
}    
else
{
       // set image original property
}
```

Comment: I know the code to increase the size of the image but its is showing expanded images randomly  in grid thanks

Comment: I have also done that please check the first method I have written in the question Is that right or please correct it.

Comment: thanks for the answer now it is working i have forgot the else condition

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `OnclickListener` of your `imageview`

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("image path"), "image/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how do you want the image to displayed?

Comment: see the image i want like this